# How to define pgfkeys for pgfplots axis environments?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfkeys

I am trying to write a function that allows to add additional environments to a `pgfplots` `axes` environment.

I have come up with the following example:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\pgfkeys{
  /myPlot/.is family, /myPlot/.cd,
  default/.style={
    axis={},
    plot={},
  },
  axisCommands/.style={},
  axis/.style={axisCommands/.style={#1}},
  plotCommands/.style={},
  plot/.style={plotCommands/.style={#1}},
}
% 
\newcommand\Example[1][]{
    \pgfkeys{/myPlot, default, #1}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \begin{axis}[/myPlot/axisCommands/.try]
    \addplot[domain=0:1,samples=10, /myPlot/plotCommands/.try] {x};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
% 
\begin{document}
\Example[axis={/pgfplots/xlabel=x, /pgfplots/ylabel=y}, plot={blue}]{}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I am able to define 'axis' and 'plot' as keys. However, the axis environments must have `/pgfplots/' in front of them. I would like to set them in the newcommand environment, but so far I have not been able to do so. When I remove it, it shows the error message

> I don't know the key '/tikz/xlabel' to which you passed 'x'

Does anyone have an explanation and/or solution for this problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Firstly, where does key `axisstyle` get defined? Secondly, in general `pgfplots` options should have default path `/tikz` or `/pgfplots` which can be defined by `\tikzset{new key/.code=...}` or `\pgfplotsset{new key/.code=...}` respectively.  You can also use `\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd, new key/.code=...}`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change the variable names. 
Thanks, I think I understand you. However, I was unable to fix this problem. I think I have somehow to say, that all keys in `axis` are of type `\pgfplots`

I also changed my example and fixed my mistake. I hope it s now clearer.

Comment: Is is acceptable that new options having default path `/pgfplots` rather than `/myPlot`?

Comment: Sorry for my late response, yes that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of usages `axis={/pgfplots/xlabel=x, /pgfplots/ylabel=y}`, you only need to change the default path to `/pgfplots/` inside

```
axis/.style={axisCommands/.style={#1}},
% and
plot/.style={plotCommands/.style={#1}},
```

A tricky detail:

- `\addplot[] ...;` resets default style of a plotting, hence the markers (filled circles in blue) are not drawn and the blue color is reset to black. To append styles to the default one, `\addplot+` is used in the following example.

A full example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\pgfkeys{
  /myPlot/.is family, /myPlot/.cd,
  default/.style={
    axis={},
    plot={},
  },
  axisCommands/.style={},
  axis/.style={axisCommands/.style={/pgfplots/.cd, #1}},
  plotCommands/.style={},
  plot/.style={plotCommands/.style={/pgfplots/.cd, #1}},
}

\newcommand\Example[1][]{
  \pgfkeys{/myPlot, default, #1}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \begin{axis}[/myPlot/axisCommands/.try]
      \addplot+[domain=0:1, samples=10, /myPlot/plotCommands/.try] {x};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
 
\begin{document}
\Example[%
  axis={xlabel=x, ylabel=y},
  % comment the following line to restore to default style (in blue)
  plot={orange, mark options={orange}}
]{}
\end{document}
```

[image]